# Как настроить вывод ошибки при нарушении правила контроллера?

Tags: php, yii2

Поставил ограничение на доступ к `action` контроллера, прописал такое правило:

```
[
  'allow' => true,
  'actions' => ['login' , 'registration'],
  'roles' => ['?'],
],
```

Все работает правильно, но как можно сделать чтоб, когда правило не выполняется (то есть по силке переходит залогиненный пользователь) **выбрасывало не стандартное предупреждение типа** :

> An Error occurred while handling another error:
>   yii\web\ForbiddenHttpException: You are not allowed to perform this
>   action.

**а показывало определенною страницу ?**

Comment: Отловить его. Try catch

Comment: @Naumov, в каждом действии ?

Comment: Я не силен в юи но думаю у контролера есть что типо метода доступности

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте свойство [`AccessControl.denyCallback`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-filters-accesscontrol.html#$denyCallback-detail), если обработчик будет одинаковый для всех правил:

```
'access' => [
    'class' => AccessControl::className(),
    'rules' => [
        [
            'actions' => ['login' , 'registration'],
            'allow' => true,
            'roles' => ['?']
        ]
    ],
    'denyCallback' => function($rule, $action) {
        Yii::$app->session->setFlash('info', 'Вам сюда нельзя!');
        return $action->controller->redirect('/site/index');
    },
]
```

либо [`AccessRule.denyCallback`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-filters-accessrule.html#$denyCallback-detail), если нужен специфический обработчик для конкретного правила:

```
'access' => [
    'class' => AccessControl::className(),
    'rules' => [
        [
            'actions' => ['login' , 'registration'],
            'allow' => true,
            'roles' => ['?'],
            'denyCallback' => function($rule, $action) {
                Yii::$app->session->setFlash('info', 'Вам сюда нельзя!');
                return $action->controller->redirect('/site/index');
            },
        ]
    ],
]
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ) такое решение меня устраивает)! Но второй пример почему-то не работает! выбрасывает то, что и без него)

Comment: спасибо, я уже разобрался что было не так! работает, когда    'allow' => false! 

А можете еще подсказать, как можно обработать ошибку в действии контроллера! Чтоб в каждом действии не отлавливать try-catch! Например при вызове каждого действия проверать какие-то параметры ?